# CiviMember Expiration Date Advancement

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, civixero

We have evolved the following method of processing (~ 400) membership renewals

(1) CiviMember Dashboard/Find Memberships

- Select appropriate expiry date and Membership Category and produce list of members requiring renewal
- Select checkbox for memberships to renew and export members to .csv

(2 Manual Step - CiviMember Dashboard/Batch Data Entry

- add New Data Entry Batch
- manually enter each Contact Name or ID number
- Renew Membership appears automatically
- Amount appears automatically
- Received date - appears automatically (but can be edited)
- Paid By - select TBA (and copy down list). [TBA payment method previously added in CiviContribute Payment Method Options, set to Default and Allocated to Accounts Receivable]
- Payment Status - select Pending and Copy Down
- Press Validate and Process the Batch

This has the following effects

1. Membership Renewal Contribution is created in Civi Contribute with
   status "Pending" and includes Membership Renewal Invoice number
2. Membership Expiry Date is advanced by 1 period
3. Membership Renewal Contribution Invoice is automatically transferred to our Xero Accounting system through CiviXero Extension

Invoices are created in Xero with appropriate annotation and Invoice Number and have status "Awaiting Approval"

Contacts have been previously exported to Xero by CiviXero and include email address

Invoices awaiting approval can be Approved in Xero and get automatically attached to the correct Contact Card.

Approved Invoices can be Bulk Emailed in Xero with appropriate template used and including any appropriate document hyperlinks

---

Then - members pay invoices by Credit Card, Cheque, Debit Card etc as appropriate

- Automatic Bank Account Transaction input appears in Xero
- Appropriate invoices can be manually reconciled as paid - the appropriate invoice is usually selected automatically in Xero to be reconciled
- Status of Invoice as Paid is automatically transmitted to CiviCRM by CiviXero
- CiviContribute payment status automatically becomes Completed
- Membership expiry date gets automatically advanced by ANOTHER period

This last step has to be manually corrected in CiviCRM by Find Memberships (eg expiring on incorrect date, use Actions drop down to Update Multiple Memberships, and correct the first to the correct date and copy down, then Update (not difficult but a bit annoying)

Two Questions

1. In the above process, how can I stop the membership expiry from being automatically updated TWICE ?
2. Is there any way that the list of members (Contacts) found for renewal in Find Memberships can be automatically uploaded into the Batch Data Entry page to avoid the need to manually add all the Members